# How do you create two priority arrays of queues in java? / Linux constant time scheduler

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, scheduling

This is a step in my assignment and it seems easy, but it seems a little confusing to me. Help would be great considering this thing is due tomorrow. Code format response would be great. Here is the step:

You will need to create two priority arrays of queues: an active array and an
expired array. In our case we will simplify and have only priority values of 0 to 4, i.e. the active array and expired array will each be comprised of 5 queues.

Comment: Err.. so what is the actual problem?  You have a queue class, so you make an array of them indexed by priority.  -1 for 'gimme de codez, urgent'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java class is `PriorityQueue`, not a "priority array".  I think you misunderstood the assignment.

Let's suppose you have an object with a priority value, and we'll leave out the restriction here.  You can put that in on your own.

```
public class Task {
    private Integer priority;  // Let's not have priorities change by accident.
    private String name;
    private double cost;
    // Constructors, getters, setters elided.
}
```

Now, a PriorityQueue needs to be of a Comparable class or be made with a Comparator.  Let's use the latter, since I'm assuming that equal priorities are equally weighted, and there's no natural ordering of `Task`.

```
public class TaskComparator implements Comparator<Task> {
    public int compare(Task left, Task right) {
        return left.getPriority() - right.getPriority();
        // Only because the numbers are limited. 
    }
}
```

You can create a PriorityQueue of Tasks with

```
PriorityQueue<Task> active = new PriorityQueue<Task>(10, new TaskComparator());
```

What you do with this is your own lookout.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. I needed clarification on that because "two priority arrays of queues" is straight from the assignment (Actually copied and pasted straight from the assignment).

Comment: Sometimes, instructors have bad days.  You need to understand what a `PriorityQueue` is used for.  IT's a collection that can store objects and provide the highest-priority item currently stored in it.  So, you are a `Student`, and you get lots of `Assignments` from your instructors.  An object representing you would contain a `PriorityQueue<Assignment>` (named *pq*, perhaps). And when you want to work on an assignment, you'd find the most important one by calling `pq.poll()`.  There are difficulties; how do you handle ties?  Or threading? What about being fair to lesser-priority assignments?